# Why does model.m2mRelation.remove() not work?

Tags: django

In  other words, why does this work:

```
if choice==Item.DO_ADD_CAT:
    for item in selected_items:
        for c in categories:
            item.categories.add(Category.objects.get(pk=c))
        item.save()
    messages.success(request,'Categories have been added.')
```

and this not:

```
if choice==Item.DO_REM_CAT:                        
    for item in selected_items:                            
        for c in categories:                                 
            item.categories.remove(Category.objects.get(pk=c))
        item.save()                            
    messages.success(request,'Categories have been removed.')
```

Isn't this supposed to be working?

**edit:**
here is the Item model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    #public/private state flags
    PRIVATE_STATUS=1
    PUBLIC_STATUS=2
    RELEASED_STATUS=3
    STATUS_CHOICES=((PRIVATE_STATUS ,'private'),
                    (PUBLIC_STATUS  ,'public' ),
                    (RELEASED_STATUS,'released'))
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                                 default=PRIVATE_STATUS,
                                )
    objects = models.Manager()
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tags=TagField()
    count=models.IntegerField(blank=True)

    def get_user_path(self,filename):
        return '%s/%s/%s' %( self.creator_id,
                             datetime.date.today(),
                             filename)
    file=models.FileField(upload_to=get_user_path)

    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='creator')
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category,related_name="items",blank=True,null=True)
```

and the Category Model:

```
class Category (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True,help_text='Optional')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Category'
        verbose_name_plural='Categories'
```

Comment: Possible reason is setting a M2M filed to null=False with django default settings... Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess i see the error... As in the django documentation tell us, you can not use remove on an foreignkey with a null=False definition... [Related documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.remove)

So prior to the logic of M2M relations, django set your m2m relation as null=False... So possibilities are:

1. change your m2m definition to null=True
2. use clear() to remove all elements...

Comment: I think you got it wrong. Django docs on queries allow this quite explicit: "Both ends of a many-to-many relationship get automatic API access to the other end. The API works just as a "backward" one-to-many relationship, above."  You can find it here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships

Comment: If using `add()` works, then I assume he's not using a through model.

Comment: Updated my code to reflect your proposal. Didn't work though. A promising guess nonetheless.

Comment: Oh wait a minute - do i have to update the database in order to have the changes take effect? I'm going to try that right away, maybe this could be it...

Comment: Yeah - thats it! Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly how it's supposed to work (especially if the first method works).

Do you get an error message? How do you know it's not working?

Is your code even getting to the remove stage? Use `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` and or pepper with print/log statements to make sure the if condition is being met at all and if the object you're trying to remove exists.

I would enter pdb inside your loop and check which categories exist and try removing one of them.

```
if choice==Item.DO_REM_CAT:                        
    for item in selected_items:                            
        for c in categories:
            import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            # now check loop.categories.all()
            # item.categories.get(pk=c)
            item.categories.remove(Category.objects.get(pk=c))                              
    messages.success(request,'Categories have been removed.')



log = []
if choice==Item.DO_REM_CAT:                        
    for item in selected_items:                            
        for c in categories:
            category = Category.objects.get(pk=c)
            try:
                item.categories.get(pk=category.pk) # just making sure what we're deleting really exists
                item.categories.remove(category.pk)
                try:
                    item.categories.get(pk=category.pk) # shouldn't be here anymore
                    log.append("Category %s Magically Still Here" %  category)
                except Category.DoesNotExist:
                    log.append("Category %s Successfully Deleted" % category)
            except Category.DoesNotExist:
                log.append("Category %s we attempted to remove from %s doesn't exist" % (category, item))

            return http.HttpResponse('<br><br>'.join(log))
```

Comment: Ok, pdb just prooved that the shown condition does work. Looks like i have to dive in deeeep. Don't even know where to start, do you have a guess?

Comment: OK, the condition works: how about `item.categories.get(pk=cat_obj)`? No error? (as in it exists), then `item.categories.remove(pk=cat_obj)` ?

Comment: get works, remove throws Type Error: remove() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'

Comment: category=Category.objects.get(pk=c) works fine, i get a Category instance back. When using that for: print item.categories.remove(category) i get None (i don't know if the Django query functions should return a value, i just tried)

Comment: I meant to say remove(cat_obj) not pk=, oops~ remove() shouldn't return a value. it silently removes even if you send it pks it doesn't have, so that's why I asked you to check if exists in the first place. I've updated the post with something you could try to debug if things are being deleted or not.

Comment: I'm going to try your proposal right now. Strange fact: item.categories.clear() doesn't work as well. I can add categories the whole day, but i can't remove them. I'm going to check if i can delete them from /admin/.

Comment: I mean, I would say you're using a through model or something BUT add isn't supposed to work for through models either.

Comment: Removing from the admin didn't work as well. When using your debug-code i ran into the Type Error: remove() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'; Using item.categories.remove(category) worked, resulting in telling me that all the categories are magically still there. I'm going to change the Questions Topic to reflect all these mysteriousities.

Comment: You're right, that should have just been remove(pk), but that's very odd! So that would make me think even from a fresh shell session the behavior would be the same? `myinstance.categories.remove(somecat.id);myinstance.categories.get(id=somecat.id)` wouldn't throw an error?

Comment: FallenAngel finally got it. Thanks for your help.